# HREF to another rendered pug file

Tags: javascript, html, href, render, pug

I'm making a website in Pug with Nodejs and Express.
I made a file called `index.pug`. In this file I included all my pug files.

**index.pug:**

```
extends ../views/layout

block content
    include home/page-content/Intro/Intro
    include home/page-content/About/About
    include home/page-content/Specialism/Specialism
    include home/page-content/Contact/Contact
    include home/page-content/Footer/Footer
```

**Intro.pug href:**

```
a(style="color: #f0ad4e", href='indexHelp')
            span(lang='nl') Help
            span(lang='en') Help
```

This `HREF` need to redirect to a file named `indexHelp.pug`. But I render all my pug files automatically to `html` files. So it can't find my indexHelp. 
`IndexHelp.pug` is like `index.pug`. When I click on that href it needs to show all the pages who are defined in `indexHelp.pug`.

Can someone please help me with my href?

***Edit***

**Routes\index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var index = require('../controllers/index');

/* Index */
// router.get('/', index.index);

router.get('/indexHelp', function(req, res) { res.render('indexHelp'); });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to have the href point to a route on your website, from which you can render the indexHelp. So:

```
a(style="color: #f0ad4e", href='//yourDomain/indexHelp')
```

Then you have a route set to accept this:

```
router.get("/indexHelp", (req, res) => {
    res.render("indexHelp");
};
```

Comment: You mentioned you're building a website in Node and Express. You should have at least one file that has the routes your application accepts. You should put the route there. If you have many routes you can split them into multiple files, but that's not a requirement.

Comment: `var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var index = require('../controllers/index');

/* Index */
router.get('/', index.index);

router.get("/indexHelp", (req, res) => {
    res.render("indexHelp");
};

module.exports = router;` 

This is my route right now, but I have a few errors

Comment: The spacing in a comment makes it hard to parse, but that looks correct!

Comment: You have the controller for you first route, so you may not have this: in your app.js or server file, make sure the line `app.set('views', 'Path to Folder with Pug files');` is set. That will let express know where your pug files are located and let you say things like `render('indexHelp')` without having to provide a full path.

Comment: I'm getting an error at this: => and this: res.render("indexJobs"); It says that the . isn't right (It says : expected)

Comment: Ah, the arrow function is JavaScript ES6 syntax. Try `router.get('/indexHelp', function(req, res) { res.render('indexHelp'); }`

Comment: This is what I now have
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var index = require('../controllers/index');

/* Index */
// router.get('/', index.index);

router.get('/indexHelp', function(req, res) { res.render('indexHelp'); });

module.exports = router;


I commented router.get(index.index

. Now I get the 404 error who is defined in my app.js

Comment: It that still doesn't work, i suggest adding the content of your routes page and app.js (or whatever you named your server page) to the question so it can be properly indented and readable. And we'll see what's going on.

Comment: I changed my question

Comment: That all looks fine, try setting the href to '/indexHelp'

Comment: My mistake then, I gave you an incorrect URL the first time :P Glad it's working now!